# Row with maximum values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table which looks like this

```
sales  units

100     1
200     3
100     2
200     4
100     5
100     1000
```

I want to select maximum sales with maximum units

for above example output should be

```
 100 1000
 200 4
```

i tried to use max function it gives wrong answer 
e.g 200 1000

Comment: I see, you have changed a question a bit. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sales, units
from tab
order by sales desc, units desc
limit 1
```

Since you have changed your question, the answer is:

```
select sales, max(units) as units
from tab
group by sales
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from youtTable where sales =(select max(sales) from yourTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by `sales`, then `units`, and take the first record:

```
select sales, units
from TheTable
order by sales desc, units desc
limit 1
```

Result:

```
sales  units
------ ------
200    4
```

#### Edit:

For the new output that you want, you need to group on the `sales` value, and use the `max` aggregate to get the highest `units` value in each group:

```
select sales, max(units)
from TheTable
group by sales
order by sales
```

Result:

```
sales  units
------ ------
100    1000
200    4
```